# Telosys says "0 tables found"

Tags: telosys

I'm using Telosys to generate Java entities from an Oracle DB. The initial `cdb dbname` command is successful.

```
telosys#(mymodel)>cdb crisdev
Checking database 'crisdev'...
OK, connection test is successful.
```

When I connect exactly like that in Sql Developer, with those exact credentials, I see the listing of all my tables.

[image]

But in Telosys, on doing `nm` I see this: **0 tables found:**

```
telosys#(mymodel)>nm devmodel crisdev
 Getting database metadata
 Getting tables metadata
 0 table(s) found
 End of metadata process
```

What's going on? There are no additional schemas in this case. The DB YAML is

```
  - id: crisdev
    name: CRIS DEV
    type: ORACLE 
    # JDBC connection
    url: <some url>
    driver: oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
    user: <some user>
    password: <some password>
    # Metadata parameters
    catalog: !
    schema: !
    tableNamePattern:
    tableNameInclude:
    tableNameExclude:
    tableTypes:
    # DB model creation
    dbModelName:
    # Telosys DSL model creation 
    linksManyToOne: true
    linksOneToMany: false
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the messages the connection is going well, but when Telosys tries to get the tables, it can't find anything.

In your database definition (yaml file) you should specify the **schema** and the **tableNamePattern** ('%' for all tables).

> **schema: SCHEMA_NAME**
> **tableNamePattern: '%'**

With Oracle "schema" = "user" (so this should be the username)

Comment: Is the `%` required? Why isn't it the default for the table names, then?

Comment: If you are using one of the latest versions of Telosys '%' is the default value. I suggest to set it just to be sure it will work in any cases (whatever the version)